# Create random coordinates with pre specified degree of clustering

Tags: r

In R, I want to create a random data frame of `x` and `y` coordinates, that has a certain degree of clustering. For example 15 $k$-means clusters.
I currently have this:

```
customer_locations <- data.frame(
  id = 1:n,
  x = round(runif(n) * grid_size),
  y = round(runif(n) * grid_size)
)
```

Comment: The phrase "a certain degree of clustering" is a bit vague. Let's say you want 15 clusters. *Any* set of points can be clustered into 15 clusters. So what specifically do you want out of the data? Do you have a specific criterion for what would make the data adequately clustered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am asking myself the same as @prubin. In case you mean with "degree" how far the clusters are from each other (and therefore also how well they are seperatable), then this might help:

```
num_clusters = 5
points_per_cluster = 10
degree = 20
allPoints = list()
for (i in 1:num_clusters){
  offsets = runif(2) * degree
  x_coord = runif(points_per_cluster) + offsets[1]
  y_coord = runif(points_per_cluster) + offsets[2]
  allPoints = rbind(allPoints, cbind(x_coord, y_coord))
}  
plot(allPoints)
```

A degree of 5 would give you sth like this:

[image]

A degree of 20 would give you sth like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes this is perfect! Thanks! Apologies for the vague explanation

Comment: Use e.g. min-max normalization to scale all values between 0 and 1